# select query returns empty in sp but when run it alone, it is not empty. Why?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I write to Table and read table. I write with no problem but when I want to read it returns empty. but it is not empty when I select query and run it returns data. Why it can be.
Here is my codes. I give fulltext index Dump and TempTable to tag,title and body columns.

```
    IF LEFT(@splitdata,1) = '#'
    BEGIN
        SET @splitdata = (SELECT REPLACE(@splitdata,'#',''))

        INSERT INTO [WebTR].[dbo].[TempTable]
                SELECT p.*
                FROM [WebTR].[dbo].[Dump] AS p 
                    INNER JOIN containstable([WebTR].[dbo].[Dump], tags, @splitdata) AS k
                    ON p.dumpID = k.[key]
    end

    SET @replacedLast += @replaced2
    FETCH NEXT FROM TableA_cursor INTO @row
```

I insert temptable first then

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM WebTR.dbo.TempTable)

BEGIN

SELECT @replacedLast AS withtag

    select dumpId,title,source,tags,creationdate,status,body,createdBy,max(rank) as rank,'olsanaaa' AS sinir
    from
    ((SELECT p.*, k.rank
    FROM WebTR.dbo.TempTable AS p
        INNER JOIN containstable(WebTR.dbo.TempTable, title,'"*cunku*"' ) AS k
        ON p.dumpID = k.[key]
        )
    union
    (
    SELECT p.*, k.rank
    FROM WebTR.dbo.TempTable AS p
        INNER JOIN containstable(WebTR.dbo.TempTable, body, '"*cunku*"') AS k
        ON p.dumpID = k.[key]

        ))y group by dumpId,title,source,tags,creationdate,status,body,createdBy
    order by rank DESC


END
```

as you can see in that if block when I select only select query it returns data but when execute stored procedure it  returns empty even it enters the if block

here is he full sp:

```
USE [WebTR]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[search]    Script Date: 10.6.2015 16:19:25 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[search]
@param1 varchar(250)
AS
BEGIN
declare @searchString varchar(250)

set @searchString = LTrim(RTrim(@param1))
TRUNCATE TABLE [WebTR].[dbo].[TempTable]

--SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @param1 ASC) AS row , * INTO #temp1 from WebTR.dbo.fnsplitstring(@searchString ,'') 
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(splitdata, 0, 2) AS CHAR(1)) desc) AS row,* INTO #params from WebTR.dbo.fnsplitstring(@searchString ,'') 

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @row INT
DECLARE @splitdata VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @replaced1 VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @replaced2 VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @replacedLast VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @last VARCHAR(500)

DECLARE TableA_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT row FROM #params
SET @last = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #params)
SET @replacedLast = ''
OPEN TableA_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM TableA_cursor INTO @row

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
        SET @splitdata = (SELECT splitdata FROM #params WHERE row=@row)

        IF LEFT(@splitdata,1) = '#'
        BEGIN
            SET @splitdata = (SELECT REPLACE(@splitdata,'#',''))
            BEGIN TRANSACTION
            INSERT INTO [WebTR].[dbo].[TempTable]
                    SELECT p.*
                    FROM [WebTR].[dbo].[Dump] AS p 
                        INNER JOIN containstable([WebTR].[dbo].[Dump], tags, @splitdata) AS k
                        ON p.dumpID = k.[key]
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
        end
        ELSE
        begin
            IF LEFT(@splitdata,1)='-'
                BEGIN
                    IF RIGHT(@replacedLast,4) = 'AND '
                        BEGIN
                            SET  @replaced1 =('NOT ')
                        END
                    ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            SET 
                             @replaced1 =('NOT ')
                        end
                        SET  @replaced2= @replaced1 + (SELECT REPLACE (@splitdata, '-', '"*'))
                        SET  @replaced2= @replaced2 + '*" ' + 'AND '
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET  @replaced2 =('"*')
                    SET  @replaced2 = @replaced2 + (SELECT @splitdata + '*" AND ')
                END
                            SET @replacedLast += @replaced2
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM TableA_cursor INTO @row
        IF @@FETCH_STATUS !=0
        BEGIN
            IF RIGHT(@replacedLast,4)='AND '
                BEGIN
                    SET @replacedLast =LEFT(@replacedLast,(LEN(@replacedLast)-3))
                END
            END
        END 
CLOSE TableA_cursor
DEALLOCATE TableA_cursor

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM WebTR.dbo.TempTable)
BEGIN
        SELECT @replacedLast AS withtag

        select dumpId,title,source,tags,creationdate,status,body,createdBy,max(rank) as rank,'olsanaaa' AS sinir
        from
        ((SELECT p.*, k.rank
        FROM WebTR.dbo.TempTable AS p
            INNER JOIN containstable(WebTR.dbo.TempTable, title,'"*cunku*"' ) AS k
            ON p.dumpID = k.[key]
            )
        union
        (
        SELECT p.*, k.rank
        FROM WebTR.dbo.TempTable AS p
            INNER JOIN containstable(WebTR.dbo.TempTable, body, '"*cunku*"') AS k
            ON p.dumpID = k.[key]

            ))y group by dumpId,title,source,tags,creationdate,status,body,createdBy
        order by rank DESC

END
    ELSE
        BEGIN

            select * into #temp1
            from
            ((SELECT p.*, k.rank
            FROM [WebTR].[dbo].[Dump] AS p 
                INNER JOIN containstable([WebTR].[dbo].[Dump], title, @replacedLast) AS k
                ON p.dumpID = k.[key]
                )
            union
            (
            SELECT p.*, k.rank
            FROM [WebTR].[dbo].[Dump] AS p 
                INNER JOIN containstable([WebTR].[dbo].[Dump], body, @replacedLast) AS k
                ON p.dumpID = k.[key]
        ))x

            select dumpId,title,source,tags,creationdate,status,body,createdBy,max(rank) as rank
            from #temp1 with (NOLOCK)
            group by dumpId,title,source,tags,creationdate,status,body,createdBy
            order by rank DESC
            DROP TABLE #temp1
        end
END
```

Comment: can you put your full sp here ?

Comment: I put full sp at the and

Comment: in your split function you are split with what ?? WebTR.dbo.fnsplitstring(@searchString, '') ?? split with empty string ????or space ?

Comment: after executing this sp the values are inserted into temptable ???

Comment: yes values inserted into temptable then I want to read from temptable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80370/discussion-between-arunprasanth-kv-and-aysekucuk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CLOSE TableA_cursor
DEALLOCATE TableA_cursor
```

did you checked this part ? Because your cursor is closing before some actions.

Comment: I'm quite sure that closing the cursors won't help in this case. But they should be closed and deallocated as well. ;-)

Comment: delete id from insert section and make it auto_inc and move truncate section to last step :)

Answer (score 1):

I have this misbehaviour in SQL Server 2008 too. If you insert and retrieve too fast with fulltext index your query won't result in the new queries.

Maybe you need a manual population of your fulltext index.

See example based on AdventureWorks

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON HumanResources.JobCandidate START UPDATE POPULATION;
GO
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142575.aspx

Hopefully the Population update will fix your issue.

Best regards,
Ionic